# DataContractJsonSerializer escaping front slashes when serializing?

Tags: c#, .net, json

I have the following helper method that I use to serialize objects:

```
public static string Serialize<T>(T obj)
{
    string json = null;

    try
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            serializer.WriteObject(stream, obj);
            byte[] bytes = stream.ToArray();
            json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }

    return json;
}
```

I noticed that when I serialize strings containing frontslashes the serialized strings end up having frontslashes escaped with backslashes. So calling the following:

```
string serialized = JsonHelper.Serialize<string>("http://abc");
```

returns `"http:\/\/abc"` as the output.

Can this unwanted behavior be avoided?

Comment: using regex/replace to remove backslashes is not an option?

Comment: Try `@"http://abc"`.

Comment: It's not an escaping related issue. Anyway I tried it and the output is identical. @ElmerDantas yes I could do a replace, but if I can avoid altogether this unwanted behavior it would be even more efficient. Also, the risk of a replace is that of replacing something that should not be replaced.